# Hamcrest: file1 either file2 exists

Tags: tdd, hamcrest

I currently refactor my tests from AsserJ to hamcrest library. But there is one assertion that I can not migrate to hamcrest.

tmp1 and tmp2 contain two paths in the filesystem. I need to verify that either tmp1 or tmp2 exists, but not both. The current assertion is

```
assertTrue(new File(tmp1).exists() ^ new File(tmp2).exists());
```

What is the equivialent hamcrest test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 assertThat(new File(tmp1).exists() ^ new File(tmp2).exists(), is(true));
```